# tensorflow multiprocessing for image feature extraction

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I have some basic function that takes in the URL of an image and transforms it via a VGG-16 CNN:

```
def convert_url(_id, url):   
  im = get_image(url)
  return _id, np.squeeze(sess.run(end_points['vgg_16/fc7'], feed_dict={input_tensor: im}))
```

I have a large set of URLs (~60,000) on which I'd like to perform this function. Each iteration takes longer than a second, which is far too slow. I'd like to speed it up by using multiple processes in parallel. There is no shared state to worry about, so the usual pitfalls of multithreading aren't an issue.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to actually get tensorflow to work with the multiprocessing package. I know that you can't pass a tensorflow `session` to a Pool variable. So instead, I tried to initialize multiple instances of `session`:

```
def init():
  global sess;
  sess = tf.Session()
```

But when I actually launch the process, it just hangs indefinitely:

```
with Pool(processes=3,initializer=init) as pool:
  results = pool.starmap(convert_url, list(id_img_dict.items())[0:5])
```

Note that the tensorflow graph is defined globally. I think that's the right way to do it but I'm not sure:

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,224,224,3), name='input_image')
scaled_input_tensor = tf.scalar_mul((1.0/255), input_tensor)
scaled_input_tensor = tf.subtract(scaled_input_tensor, 0.5)
scaled_input_tensor = tf.multiply(scaled_input_tensor, 2.0)

arg_scope = vgg_arg_scope()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
  _, end_points = vgg_16(scaled_input_tensor, is_training=False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
```

Can anyone help me get this working? Much obliged.

Comment: If you're working with online files, you should probably look at using async, which should yield a pretty big speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about python's normal multithreading tools and use a [tensorflow.contrib.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset). Try something like the following.

```
urls = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', ...]
batch_size = 16
n_batches = len(urls) // batch_size  # do something more elegant for remainder


def load_img(url):
    image = tf.read_file(url, name='image_data')
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3, name='image')
    return image


def preprocess(img_tensor):
    img_tensor = (tf.cast(img_tensor, tf.float32) / 255 - 0.5)*2
    img_tensor.set_shape((256, 256, 3))  # whatever shape
    return img_tensor


dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(urls)
dataset = dataset.map(load_img).map(preprocess)

preprocessed_images = dataset.batch(
    batch_size).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()


arg_scope = vgg_arg_scope()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
    _, end_points = vgg_16(preprocessed_images, is_training=False)
    output = end_points['vgg_16/fc7']


results = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
    for i in range(n_batches):
        batch_results = sess.run(output)
        results.extend(batch_results)
        print('Done batch %d / %d' % (i+1, n_batches))
```

Comment: Appreciate the response!  This seems like a good method if I held all the files locally. However, I only store URLs to the jpeg or png file online. Obviously it's trivial to actual use `urllib` or `requests` to get the image file itself, but does that undercut the value of using `Datasets` to parallelize the graph?

Comment: I see. In that case, you can largely ignore this answer. I haven't done much normal python multithreading, but I imagine if you parallelize the data fetching (seperately from tensorflow) you should be able to just use your code above with a batch size > 1 to significantly improve speed, e.g. fetch 16 images, feed to tf.sess when all are loaded.

Comment: I would prefer to have each thread responsible both for the data fetching and for the tensorflow transformation, as it's a cleaner solution. Your solution would work, although I wonder how much speed up there would be fetching 16 images at once via multiprocessing. That said, it does make sense that even if I sequentially grabbed those 16 images, I could then run those through VGG in parallel, so that should work. I'll still hold out someone knows how to do what I originally wanted though!

Comment: How long does it take to fetch vs run the session? If not long I'd forget about multithreading entirely and just do batch runs. I suspect multithreading the TF session will require a separate session for each thread

Comment: Running the session doesn't take that long. Doing a batch run is definitely a good call, but multiprocessing the fetches will speed up things as well. 6 threads ended up being roughly 3x faster than 1 thread (on the fetches), so it's a decent workaround.