# Multiprocessing ResNet Feature Extraction with Image URLs

Tags: keras, multiprocessing, resnet

I have a simple function to take an image url and extract features from it using resnet in Keras then hand it off to an Xgboost model loaded from a pkl file.

```py
def classify(img, resnet_model, loaded_model):
  try:
    images = io.imread(img.strip())
    images = Image.fromarray(images)
    test_image = img.resize((224,224))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    img_data = preprocess_input(test_image)
    image_features = resnet_model.predict(img_data)
    image_features_array = array(image_features)
    predicted_image = loaded_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(DataFrame(image_features_array))) 
  except:
    predicted_image = 'Broken URL'

  return predicted_image`
```

Currently I am just looping through a list of img urls and it works fine but I will need it to perform much faster.  The code itself may not be the most efficient yet but I am mostly concerned with multiprocessing.  My attempts either hang or immediately result in an empty list.

There is a similar question posted years ago here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909738/tensorflow-multiprocessing-for-image-feature-extraction) but the answers were not very satisfying and involved holding a batch of image files locally. I would prefer to just have one worker making the request for the image and then predicting that image.